# Is the below two statements i.e. Statement 1 and 2 differ in time complexities?

Tags: python, python-3.x, time

Explain the two statements that if they differ in time complexities or they are same.

```py
Good=True
#Statement 1 below
if Good:
        a=0;b=0  #print some statements
#Statement 2 below
if Good==True:
        a=0;b=0 #print some statements
```

Comment: The two statements aren't distinguished by *time complexity*, they are distinguished by *correctness*...  You almost never want to explicitly compare to `True` or `False` in Python, as that arbitrarily limits you to a few specific values that will be accepted - rather than making use of the inherent Boolean value that all Python objects possess.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```py
if good == True
```

will take longer. This is because there is an extra comparison. If you dig into how an if statement works, it evaluates the statement to see if it's true. In this case, what is happening is:

```py
if True #statement 1
if True == True #statement 2
```

The extra comparison will, in fact, take more time. Now, this time probably isn't marginal, but if used in iteration, it can make a difference, though still probably not noticeable.

Speed, however, probably isn't the big issue here. Rather, it's style (yes, style). Quoting PEP8, or Python Enhancement Proposals,

> Don't compare boolean values to True or False using ==:
>
> ```py
> # Correct:
> if greeting:
>
> # Wrong:
> if greeting == True:
>
> # Worse:
> if greeting is True:
> ```